# control circuit of humanoid robot: is it worth to learn and use ROS

Tags: microcontroller, control-system, robot

i am building the upper body of a humanoid robot for my MSc thesis project with 24 dc motors
and multiple sensors(something like i-cub or Nao) i have basic
 knowledge of communication protocols and have worked with micros befor but no knowledge and experience of 
working with ROS. the question i have is, is it worth and practical for me to learn ROS and use this for my  robot 
or should i stick with what i already know